# Unable to load daemon and service exit with a return value of 3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

Could someone help me with this problem? It seems like I can't execute the `startDSEService.sh` file. The permission allowing execution of the file is ticked and I tried `chmod +x path/of/startDSEService.sh`  as well. It still doesn't work.

`startDSEService.sh` was downloaded from this link: https://github.com/opendedup/sdfs/blob/master/install-packages/deb/usr/share/sdfs/startDSEService.sh

```
root@dsi-VirtualBox:/sbin# java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.network.ClusteredHCServer.setup(ClusteredHCServer.java:115)
    at org.opendedup.sdfs.network.ClusteredHCServer.init(ClusteredHCServer.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:207)
Cannot load daemon
Service exit with a return value of 3
```

Comment: We need more info; how do you execute `daemon.sh`. From a shell, or from some other application? What does `daemon.sh` contain?

Comment: Sjon, i edited my post with more details about it. I execute it from terminal.

Comment: It appears that you very much *can* execute that script.  It runs, it starts a mystery Java program, and the mystery Java program crashes.